# How to subscribe to specific registry id in google cloud platform (GCP) in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, iot, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm using google IOT core.
I have created multiple device registry,
but all devices emitting data to the same topic.
I want to subscribe to topic based on registry id.
Is there any method to subscribe to the topic along with registryId ?

Comment: You might get a better result on the forums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep the topics and devices separated, you can create a registry for each topic that you want to publish data; however, you can also set up different topics in a single registry. This is done using the concept of ["subfolders"](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/devices#creating_a_device_registry_with_multiple_pubsub_topics).

On a registry you can add different Pub/Sub topics, linked to a subfolder.

Then, you can push data to those specific topics. In MQTT by [setting the subfolder in the MQTT topic](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/mqtt-bridge#publishing_telemetry_events_to_additional_cloud_pubsub_topics), and in [HTTP by specifying a subfolder](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/http-bridge#publishing_telemetry_events_to_separate_pubsub_topics) in the subFolder field in the publishEvent method.

Example using MQTT:

```js
// In the device configuration, add the subfolder at the end of the MQTT Topic

const mqttTopic = `/devices/${deviceId}/${messageType}/${subfolder}`;
```

In the registry, add an additional Pub/Sub topic with the subfolder name.

[image: Pub/Sub configuration in registry]

Now, when publishing data to the registry, it will go to the topic with the subfolder that you used